# Submit button not working- if else statement

Tags: php, mysql

I want my submit button to,when clicked, run an if else statement. In the field 'complete' in my users table, if the value  is 6 or above an email should send (I have this code), if not then it should display an error or redirect to an error page (which I can create). This is my attempt but the error message shows even when the value is 6

```
$usr_email = 'usr_email';
$user_name = 'user_name';
{
$sqltest = "SELECT complete From users where user_id =
".intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
}
if (isset($_POST['doSend'])) {

function getOne($query){
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$res) {
        trigger_error("db: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        return $row[0];
    }

$isSending = getOne($sqltest);
$isSending === false;
if($isSending >= 6){
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "<xxx>";
$to = "$usr_email";
$subject = "Hi";
$body = hello ";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    header ("Location: error.php");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where's your form and what's its target?

Comment: ` <form action="myaccount.php" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >`
It has no target?

Comment: @Madbreaks i'm trying  to improve:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<p align="center">
    <input name="doSend" type="submit" id="doSend" value="Submit Application">
</p>
```

to

```
<form name="input" action="myaccount.php" method="post">
    <input name="doSend" type="submit" id="doSend" value="Submit Application">
</form>
```

You need to add an `else` in the outer `if` statement.

```
$isSending = getOne($sqltest);
$isSending === false;
if($isSending >= 6){
    require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "<xxx>";
    $to = "$usr_email";
    $subject = "Hi";
    $body = hello ";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
}
else
    header ("Location: error.php");
```

Comment: Thanks now it just redirects to error page even when the value is 6 :( See edit

Comment: Sorry the error page is the page it redirects to if the number is less than 6. Its not an actual error

Comment: You are certain that `getOne($sqltest)` outputs a 6 or greater? Try removing this line `$isSending === false;`

Comment: Still doing the same. I will add some more of the mail code to my question see if that is affecting the else statement

Comment: Your if statement is evaluating correctly.  If `PEAR::isError($mail)` returns false, that means there's no error and goes to the else.  Your else shouldn't contain the `header ("Location: error.php");`

Comment: But thats where I want it to redirect if the number is below 6 to the error.php page. Is this where I am going wrong? the else should be activated IF the number is below 6, above 6 and the email should be sent

Comment: Can you post the whole `if($isSending >= 6)` block of code? I really can't tell where that else is supposed to be with the code broken up like that.  Is that else supposed to be with `if (PEAR::isError($mail))` or `if($isSending >= 6)`?

Comment: From the looks of your code, the `if else` is nested inside the `if($isSending >= 6)`.  That else is part of your `if (PEAR::isError($mail))`.  If you want an error page, you'll need to add an else outside.  Like this.

Comment: Thank you!the sent message appears but  I haven't got the email so must be something with my email code. Thanks for your help and sticking with it!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have a form around it? How about this:

```
<p align="center">
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <input name="doSend" type="submit" id="doSend" value="Submit Application">
</form>
</p>
```

@your comment: even if it is higher then 6? Like this?

```
$isSending = getOne(9);
```

Comment: Thanks now it just redirects to the error page even when the value is above 6. See edit

Comment: I get this when editing that line `db: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '9' `

Answer (score 0):

In most if not all browsers, a submit button does nothing if not in a <form/>, does your html have a <form>Tag Around your <input/></form>? If not, wrap your input tag in a form and it will work.

Comment: This is not an answer, please put questions in a comment on the original post.

Comment: Just 'cause this isn't Jeopardy doesn't mean that's not an answer.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't *answer the question* means it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition terminates before the second `if` statement:

```
function getOne($query){
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$res) {
        trigger_error("db: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    return $row[0];
}
```

should be:

```
function getOne($query){
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$res) {
        trigger_error("db: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        return $row[0];
    }
}
```

As it is now, the value obtained from the sql query is never returned.